# Digital image processing error via python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, classification

I want to get a process that reads the image with tensorflow in python, classifies the read image and gives the disease names in this classification; but when I read my training file and upload the picture, it cannot diagnose from the picture. I am using the code snippet below. Can you help me?

```
def callback():  
  cell="\n IMAGE FILE NOT UPLOADED..."  
  try:
    model = load_model('a95e30model.h5')
    #model.summary()
    test_image=image.load_img(red("upload"),target_size=(50,50,3))
    #imgplot = plt.imshow(test_image)
    #plt.show()
    test_image=image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image=expand_dims(test_image,axis=0)
    result = model.predict(test_image)
    result=ndarray.round(result)
    cell="PARASITIZED" if result[0][1]==1 else "UNINFECTED"
    output.set("\n "+cell+" CELL DETECTED !\n");print(cell)
  except:
    output.set(cell);print("EXCEPTION")
```

Comment: what happens when you run this? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I found this from the sample project, but I cannot study my own education. It works but cannot diagnose from the training set. When I include my own training file cell = "\ n THE IMAGE FILE IS NOT UPLOADED ..." I get an output like this. It does not classify. How will I include the classification process with codes.